# Obtener el return de un procedimiento almacenado en SQLServer desde Java

Tags: java, sql

No estoy seguro de que sea la manera correcta de hacerlo, si no es así, me gustaría que me propucionan alternativas.

Quiero saber cómo es posible obtener el la misma salida en la aplicación que estoy desarrollando en Netbeans que obtengo en SQL Server. Todo esto con fin de crear una especie de Login de usuarios que existen en la base de datos.

[image: salida en SQLServer]

Tengo una clase conexión que funciona perfectamente, ya he hecho pruebas con ella. Intenté implementar el siguiente código para obtener lo que necesito, pero no sé como obtener el dato y hacer `true` mi bandera `encontrado` para indicar que el usuario sí existe.

```
String auxN = txtusuario.getText();
    String auxP = txtPassword.getText();
    boolean encontrado = false;
    try {
        con = conexiones.Conexion();
        CallableStatement proc = con.prepareCall("{call InicioSesion(?)}");
        proc.setString(1, auxN);
        proc.execute();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error :c");
    }
    //if (con.Conexion(txtusuario.getText(), txtPassword.getText()) != null) {
    if (encontrado == true) {
        MenuPrincipal mp = new MenuPrincipal();
        mp.setVisible(true);
        conexiones.cierraConexion();
        dispose();
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario y password incorrectos", "error de conexion", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        txtusuario.setText("");
        txtPassword.setText("");
        txtusuario.requestFocus();
    }
```

Tengo entendido que con esta linea de código `CallableStatement proc = con.prepareCall("{call InicioSesion(?)}");` estoy mandando llamar al procedimiento que se encuentra en la imagen y que con el `proc.setString(1, auxN);` le mando el parámetro obtenido del campo de texto del usuario.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar el método proc.executeQuery(), que retorna un ResultSet que luego puedes inspeccionar para obtener el valor que necesitas.
Por lo que veo tu stored procedure solo retorna una fila y una columna, por lo que simplemente deberías ser algo así:

```
ResultSet rs = proc.executeQuery();
encontrado = rs.first();
```

Esto funciona porque first() retorna true si existe una primera fila en el resultSet (lo que significa que encontraste tu usuario), si no hay ningún resultado, retorna false.

Comment: No sé la razón del porqué no funcionó con el método «first», busqué la documentación y no entendí el porque siempre retornaba false, opté por usar «next» y con ese me funcionó.